# Isearch return t if found for loop function in Emacs Lisp

Tags: function, loops, emacs, while-loop

How to write a function where whenever a variable is found, it returns t (in order to allow a loop):

```
(setq x 1)
(while ("backward search for regexp "%x" equals true") ;where x is variable
  (setq x (+ x 1))
(insert (concat "%" (int-to-string x)))
)
```

Example: If %1 (x=1) is found, it will add 1 to x. If %2 (x=2) is found, it will add 1 to x.
Let's say %3 is not found in a backward search, the while loop stops and "%" + "3" is inserted (%3).

I just don't understand the how to return true on a backward-search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`search-backward` takes an optional third argument which, when non-nil, tells it to return nil in case the search was unsuccessful:

```lisp
(setq x 1)
(while (search-backward (format "%%%d" x) nil t)
  (setq x (1+ x)))
(insert (format "%%%d" x))
```

---

Now, if I try to understand what you really want to do (something like inserting at point the first `%d` string which doesn't appear before), then you might want to wrap the search inside a `save-excursion` form to avoid moving the point:

```lisp
(setq x 1)
(while (save-excursion (search-backward (format "%%%d" x) nil t))
  (setq x (1+ x)))
(insert (format "%%%d" x))
```

Comment: Apart from switching 1+ to + 1, I do not understand the format part? does %%%d equal "%" in a search?

Comment: `format` takes a string as its first argument. This string represents a format which will be used to output the following arguments. `%d` formats a number, `%s` a string, and `%%` is the `%` symbol itself. THis construct is a bit more concise than `(concat "%" (int-to-string x))`

Answer (score 1):

With help from [Francesco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1225607/francesco)

```
(defun Navi-insert-question ()
  (interactive)
  (setq x 1)
  (while (save-excursion 
  (search-backward (concat comment-start " Question: " (int-to-string x)) nil t))
  (setq x (+ 1 x)))
  (insert (concat comment-start " Question: " (int-to-string x))))
```

It now results in being able to insert in R, for instance: "# Question: 1", when it exists above in the buffer it will insert "# Question: 2".